# Is it possible to get recent 10 emails using Gmail-api?

Tags: python, gmail-api

For now, I can use gmail api to get all UNREAD emails or all emails in INBOX.

```
GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['UNREAD', 'INBOX']).execute()
```

Because getting all the emails could be annoying, I was wondering is it possible to get only the recent 10 UNREAD emails from gmail api?

Thanks for any hint that will allow me to do such thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#list) tells us that we need to pass `maxResults` and set it to 10:

```
GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['UNREAD'], maxResults=10).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through this [doc](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

You can query using the advanced search options.

You may use

newer_than:

Example: newer_than:2d

Search for messages older or newer than a time period using d (day), m (month), and y (year)

Comment: This doc is for gmail not gmail-API

Answer (score 0):

```
GMAIL.users().messages().list(
    userId="me",
    labelIds=["UNREAD", "INBOX"],
    maxResults=10,
    q="newer_than:6d"
).execute()
```